# how to convert minutes to hours in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want output as :- `-11:25` but getting `-685` in minutes

```
select ClientName, JobName, JobTime, FileWriteTime,
    CAST(FileWriteTime as time(0))[Time],
        (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(FileWriteTime as time(0)),
        CONVERT(datetime,JobTime,120))) as Minutes
from StaleFileReport 
where ClientName ='AIA' and JobName ='MY-PTACOMB-TRD-LD' and convert(varchar,ReportTime,102) 
in ('2018.09.03','2018.09.10','2018.09.17','2018.09.24') order by convert(varchar,ReportTime,102)**
```

Comment: Please don't tag 3 completely different RDBMS. Oracle, SQL Server and MySQL are all very different products. This looks like SQL Server, due to the use of `CONVERT` with a style code, however, please update your tags with the RDBMS you are using and **only** the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Also, `-11:25` isn't a time. Time doesn't have negative values.

Comment: An interval can have negative values!

Answer (score 0):

change your query as below

```
select ClientName, JobName, JobTime, FileWriteTime,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),FileWriteTime,108) HourMinute
from StaleFileReport 
where ClientName ='AIA' and JobName ='MY-PTACOMB-TRD-LD' and convert(varchar,ReportTime,102) 
in ('2018.09.03','2018.09.10','2018.09.17','2018.09.24') order by convert(varchar,ReportTime,102)
```